# script that zips and names files within their enclosing folder

Tags: macos, bash, unix, terminal, automation

I'm trying to write a bash script where I can give it a main directory which contains multiple folders and zip the contents of the folders (excluding their enclosing folder) and renames the zip to that of their enclosing folder.

Here is a visual example that should explain what I'm trying to achieve better.

```
|ROOT FOLDER
   > Folder_1
      - file
      - folder
      - file
   > Folder_2
      - file
      - folder
      - file
   > Folder_3
      - file
      - folder
      - file
```

I want to be able to target the `ROOT FOLDER` and it return zipped files. Here's an example of the exported zips and their contents.

```
|ROOT FOLDER
   > zips 
      > Folder_1.zip
         - file
         - folder
         - file
      > Folder_2.zip
         - file
         - folder
         - file
      > Folder_3.zip
         - file
         - folder
         - file
```

I hope that makes sense. I do a lot of this and thought this can definitely be automated, though my bash scripting knowledge is limited.

Comment: I haven't yet. Currently I manually do each zip but in regards to this I don't know where start when it comes to targeting files within folders and zipping them as part of a group.

Comment: Do you need the bash script specifically? Or can you run, let's say a python script?

Comment: Python would work too, I just wanted to be specific for the sake of the question.

Answer (score 1):

this creates a zip files in the folder that near the root folder. You are free to play with it as you wish till it will fit your requirements

```
#!/bin/bash

function usage(){
  echo "Usage: $(basename $0) <root folder path>"
  exit 1
}

[ $# -eq 0 ] && usage

root=$1
pushd ${root}
folders=$(find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1)
[ -d ../zips ] || mkdir ../zips
for folder in $folders
do
  pushd $folder
  zip -r ../../zips/$(basename ${folder}).zip .
  popd
done
popd
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. I'm able to get it to work by declaring the actual root 'root="home/desktop/folder"'.

I'm using Terminal to call the script file and it's when it asks "Please enter a root path", I enter the pathname home/desktop/folder and nothing happens.

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand. does it work or doesn't?

Comment: If I remove the 'usage()' function and change 'root="root/path/folder"', it works.

Comment: got it, with a `usage` function you should pass the root as an argument to the script

Comment: I've edited the answer with a more useful  usage message

Comment: This is interesting. I have a folder on my desktop with the folders in it. The bash script is on my desktop and it appears to zip all the desktop folders and put them in my root. I have to place the bash file within the folder for it to work as intended. Thank you for updating the messages btw

Comment: if you remove the `usage` function and doesn't provide an argument for the script, this will be a behavior. run it by `scirpt.sh path/to/folder`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81551/discussion-between-marcusmichaels-and-yuri-g).